# Applescript System Events Keystroke broken after 10.9.4

Tags: terminal, applescript

It seems like the recent Mavericks update has broken the keystroke command in applescript -- whenever my script reaches that point, it freezes. (I currently have ~20 zombie osascript processes...)

Furthermore, there isn't anything in the accessibility options to allow applescripts to automate keystrokes.

This is my script currently.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
end tell
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    keystroke "t" using command down
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd ~/some_folder_here" in front window
end tell
```

If there's a way to tell terminal to directly open a tab (or if iterm 2 can do that) that could also be a solution.

Comment: Just tried your AppleScript here on 10.9.4 and it successfully brings Terminal to the foreground and opens a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the System Events process on my machine was frozen (which I discovered after a node process refused to be killed). Performing a full restart fixed the problem.